# rightclick event in Qt to open a context menu

Tags: c++, qt, events, contextmenu

I have a segment of code that calls a mousePressEvent. I have the left-click output the coordinates of the cursor, and I have rightclick do the same, but I also want to have the rightclick open a context menu. The code I have so far is:

```
void plotspace::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*event)
{
    double trange = _timeonright - _timeonleft;
    int twidth = width();
    double tinterval = trange/twidth;

    int xclicked = event->x();

    _xvaluecoordinate = _timeonleft+tinterval*xclicked;



    double fmax = Data.plane(X,0).max();
    double fmin = Data.plane(X,0).min();
    double fmargin = (fmax-fmin)/40;
    int fheight = height();
    double finterval = ((fmax-fmin)+4*fmargin)/fheight;

    int yclicked = event->y();

    _yvaluecoordinate = (fmax+fmargin)-finterval*yclicked;

    cout<<"Time(s): "<<_xvaluecoordinate<<endl;
    cout<<"Flux: "<<_yvaluecoordinate<<endl;
    cout << "timeonleft= " << _timeonleft << "\n";

    returncoordinates();

    emit updateCoordinates();

    if (event->button()==Qt::RightButton)
    {
            contextmenu->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

            connect(contextmenu, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),
            this, SLOT(ShowContextMenu(const QPoint&)));

            void A::ShowContextMenu(const QPoint &pos) 
            {
                QMenu *menu = new QMenu;
                menu->addAction(tr("Remove Data Point"), this,  
                SLOT(test_slot()));

                menu->exec(w->mapToGlobal(pos));
            }

    }   

}
```

I know that my problem is very fundamental in nature, and that 'contextmenu' is not properly declared. I have pieced together this code from many sources, and do not know how to declare something in c++. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`customContextMenuRequested` is emitted when the widget's contextMenuPolicy is `Qt::CustomContextMenu`, and the user has requested a context menu on the widget. So in the constructor of your widget you can call `setContextMenuPolicy` and connect `customContextMenuRequested` to a slot to make a custom context menu.

In the constructor of `plotspace` :

```
this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), 
        this, SLOT(ShowContextMenu(const QPoint &)));
```

`ShowContextMenu` slot should be a class member of `plotspace` like :

```
void plotspace::ShowContextMenu(const QPoint &pos) 
{
   QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);

   QAction action1("Remove Data Point", this);
   connect(&action1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(removeDataPoint()));
   contextMenu.addAction(&action1);

   contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the lifetime of locally defined variables are restricted to the domain that they are defined. For example, here contextMenu and action1 are local variables and when the function ShowContextMenu riches its end, they become deleted. So why does the above code still work? Shouldn't we define these variables as member variables of the corresponding class?

Comment: @alireza `exec` function in `QMenu` executes the menu synchronously. i.e. the function does not reach it's end and waits at `exec`  until the menu is closed.